# What is causing my variables names to get parsed like this in lme4?

Tags: r, lme4

I am experiencing an issue where the Groups names for my variables are getting unexpectedly parsed with something like `make.names` under the hood.

See how the original variables are `asset`, `product`, `batch_id`, but the Groups names appear like (for example) `batch_id..product.asset..1`.  This is making it difficult for me to work with the random effects coefficients `re(model)` and the random effects variances `VarCorr(model)` because the names no longer match after the parsing.

```
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: log10(y) ~ ((1 | asset/product/batch_id) + (0 + x | asset/product/batch_id)) +      x
   Data: as.data.frame(dat)
REML criterion at convergence: -132.5519
Random effects:
 Groups                     Name        Std.Dev.
 batch_id..product.asset.   x           0.008799
 batch_id..product.asset..1 (Intercept) 0.202142
 product.asset              x           0.012652
 product.asset.1            (Intercept) 0.116187
 asset                      x           0.000000
 asset.1                    (Intercept) 0.139519
 Residual                               0.126896
Number of obs: 307, groups:  batch_id:(product:asset), 89; product:asset, 21; asset, 4
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.76454     -0.06939  
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings
```

I actually can't reproduce the result on other data sets.  Here, the Groups have useful names like `Subject:(Sex:cohort)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

data(Orthodont, package = "nlme")

dat <- Orthodont %>% 
  mutate(cohort = if_else(parse_number(as.character(Subject)) > 6, "A", "B"))

(model <- lmer(distance ~ age + (age | cohort/Sex/Subject), data = dat))
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: distance ~ age + (age | cohort/Sex/Subject)
#>    Data: dat
#> REML criterion at convergence: 438.8359
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups               Name        Std.Dev.  Corr 
#>  Subject:(Sex:cohort) (Intercept) 2.268e+00      
#>                       age         1.790e-01 -0.61
#>  Sex:cohort           (Intercept) 6.037e-01      
#>                       age         1.598e-01 -1.00
#>  cohort               (Intercept) 7.485e-05      
#>                       age         3.235e-05 1.00 
#>  Residual                         1.310e+00      
#> Number of obs: 108, groups:  Subject:(Sex:cohort), 27; Sex:cohort, 4; cohort, 2
#> Fixed Effects:
#> (Intercept)          age  
#>     16.8545       0.6355  
#> optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you might have a better shot at reproducing this if you set up a model with multiple RE terms with the same grouping variable (e.g. like the `(1 | asset/product/batch_id) + (0 + x | asset/product/batch_id)` in your first example)